# Regex validate array after question mark

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate string if has following format

```
anyName?[anyName=anyName;anyName=anyName]
```

where anyName is combination of all digits letters from Aa-Zz and 0-9
and number of pairs anyName=anyName in the [] is at least one

Started with this `[A-Za-z0-9]+\?[[A-Za-z0-9]=[A-Za-z0-9]....]` any help ?

Comment: You need to escape the square brakets as well.

Comment: also add `+` after `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+\?\[[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:;[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)*]$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B%5C%3F%5C%5B%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B%3D%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3A%3B%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B%3D%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%2B)*%5D%24&i=anyName%3F%5BanyName%3DanyName%3BanyName%3DanyName%5D)

**Breakdown**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumerics
- `\?` - a literal `?`
- `\[` -  a literal `[`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric symbols
- `=`  -  a literal `=`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric symbols
- `(?:;[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `;` - a literal `;` and
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+` - see above
- `]` - a literal `]`
- `$` - end of string

Shortening it a bit with the case-insensitive modifier and `\d`:

```
(?i)^[A-Z\d]+\?\[[A-Z\d]+=[A-Z\d]+(?:;[A-Z\d]+=[A-Z\d]+)*]$
```

And to make `\d` only match `0-9` range without allowing Unicode digits, compile with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

A possible C# regex declaration is:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z\d]+\?\[[A-Z\d]+=[A-Z\d]+(?:;[A-Z\d]+=[A-Z\d]+)*]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

Comment: Just a note after reading the Charles' answer: The  `+` quantifier matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern and `*` matches *zero* or more. Thus, whenever you allow an empty string, replace the `+` with `*`. So, to match `?[=]` you need `(?i)^[A-Z\d]*\?\[[A-Z\d]*=[A-Z\d]*(?:;[A-Z\d]*=[A-Z\d]*)*]$`. This part is unclear in the question.

Comment: and what is (?i) ?

Comment: It is the case insensitive inline modifier. You may remove it and compile the Regex with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option. Also, if it is validation, I'd rather use `\z` instead of `$` at the end (as `$` can match before the final newline).

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet since reputation, but Wiktor's answer assumes that `anyName` itself is at least one character long. If that's not the case you need to do this

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*\?\[[A-Za-z0-9]*=[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:;[A-Za-z0-9]*=[A-Za-z0-9]*)*]$
```

- `*` matches 0 or more
- `+` matches 1 or more
- `{x, y}` matches between x and y inclusive